# apply css rule only when device is horizontal

Tags: html, css, mobile

I need to apply some css to a mobile device (all cell phones, android iPhone etc.), but only when the device is horizontal. When the device is vertical, nothing will appear (the page is blank), and a different css will load for desktop.

I've got the desktop CSS mostly working, but can't for the life of me figure out what to do w/ the rest. It's also a huge jumbled mess atm. I've no idea what to try next.

any help would be very much appreciated!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge"/>
<title>Untitled</title>
<!--Adobe Edge Runtime-->
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="romneyMorph_edgePreload.js">            </script>
<style>
    .edgeLoad-EDGE-455562748 { visibility:hidden; }

.MobileMorph{
outline:1px solid red;
}  

@media only screen and (max-device-width : 1223px) and (orientation : landscape){
.DesktopMorph {
display: none;
}
}

@media only screen and (max-device-width : 1223px) and (orientation : portrait){
.MobileMorph, .DesktopMorph {
display:none;
}
}

@media only screen and (min-width : 1224px){
.MobileMorph {
display: none;
}
}

@media only screen and (min-width : 1224px){
.MobileMorph {
display: none;
}
}
</style>
<!--Adobe Edge Runtime End-->



</head>
<body style="margin:0;padding:0;">

<div id="everything">
<!--MOBILE-->
<div class="DesktopMorph" align="center">
<iframe src="google.com" width="1024" height="344" frameBorder="0" style="outline: none; border: 0px;"></iframe>
</div>

<!--DESKTOP-->
<div class="MobileMorph" align="center">
<iframe src="index.html" width="690" height="322" frameBorder="0" style="outline: none;         border: 0px;"></iframe>
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#orientation

Answer (score 6):

Media queries can do that:

```
@media only screen and (orientation: landscape) {
    /* css rules */
}
```

Use "portrait" for vertical.

Comment: this is what i'm doing, if you look at the code. it's still not working correctly for some reason.

Comment: Maybe drop the `and (max-device-width : 1223px) `  in front?

Comment: that fixed the problem i was having w/ the desktop versions also showing mobile, but my mobile version is still showing the desktop when vertical, instead of showing nothing.

Comment: Plus it's pretty pointless to specify `only screen`. Are you worried that a screen reader or braille browser will not visually render correctly when it identifies its nonexistent orientation?

Comment: Perhaps the orientation of the device is being reported based on the zoomed-out shape of the page rather than the viewport shape.

Comment: "only screen" also affects print layout.

Comment: @Anthony I'm not a web dev, doing a web dev's job, so that makes no sense to me at all. I'm guessing probably not?? I was given this code to use as a starting point and clearly it hasn't been working for me very well

Comment: @richremer i suppose that could also be true, but again i would have no idea how to test for that or try to fix it

Comment: @rich - you mean print and page are non screen media that have orientation? Good catch.

Comment: You may want to take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag.  There may be a way to get the orientation to trigger by playing with the viewport meta value.  This controls how mobile browsers scale down a desktop-sized page and may be affecting the way orientation is triggered.